# How to attach an onclick event on a link for using a javascript feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an edit button using bootstrap 2(i know version 3 has released)in my admin pannel , the code for which is :

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" id="my-button" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a>
```

Now, when i click this , i want the following to execute ,

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#my-button').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                appendTo: 'form'
                , zIndex: 8
                ,easing: 'easeOutBack'
                ,speed: 450
                ,transition: 'slideDown'

            });
        });
     });
 })(jQuery);
```

I tried making a javascript function and then calling this inside it , but it's not working. So please , can you help me as how can i bind onclick event here ? Any suggestion will really help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error , my code doesn't give any output . I tried using the Inspect element , console tab for any error , but dint saw any. actually if we can discuss it on skype would be better for the problem solving.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: @sawa : you are just a moron who is downvoting all my questions on stackoverflow , just to degrade my reputation. Grow up child , you need some good mental treatment.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my solution , as the problem was in the sequence of calling the Jquery libraries. I just had to rearrange the order of the called libraries.But ,thank you for all your suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#my-button').click(function(e) {
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                appendTo: 'form',
                zIndex: 8,
                easing: 'easeOutBack',
                speed: 450,
                transition: 'slideDown'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also you should add a "href='#'" to the A tag. Some browsers don't render A tags correctly if they are missing an 'href'.

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" id="my-button" href='#' title="Edit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a>
```

Comment: Sir , i did according to your suggestions , but still no results . It would be better if u can see my code live , for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an anchor tag, you should add `href="#"` for safety purposes. I would make the javascript lot more simpler in this manner :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
           $('#my-button').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                appendTo: 'form'
                , zIndex: 8
                ,easing: 'easeOutBack'
                ,speed: 450
                ,transition: 'slideDown'
             });
            return false; });
});
```

Comment: $('document').ready wont work and should be done as $(document).ready or better yet just the shorthand of $(function(){});

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann Doesn't really matter. I have been using $('document') for all my life. Anyway thanks for the shorthand

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the code does work. You may have other things conflicting. It'd be best if you could provide a link to the live code.

I have a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/7bcp54hr/3/) as an example.

The JavaScript portion should not be placed inside of another function. Not sure if this is what you meant be

> I tried making a javascript function and then calling this inside it

Test out the working example

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            appendTo: 'form',
            zIndex: 8,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            speed: 450,
            transition: 'slideDown'
        });
        return false;
    });
});

/*
 * Do Not Copy this section. It is just the source file for the bPopUp Library
 */
/*********************************************************************************
 * @name: bPopup
 * @author: (c)Bjoern Klinggaard (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup - twitter@bklinggaard)
 * @version: 0.7.0.min
 *********************************************************************************/
(function(b){b.fn.bPopup=function(n,p){function t(){b.isFunction(a.onOpen)&&a.onOpen.call(c);k=(e.data("bPopup")||0)+1;d="__bPopup"+k;l="auto"!==a.position[1];m="auto"!==a.position[0];i="fixed"===a.positionStyle;j=r(c,a.amsl);f=l?a.position[1]:j[1];g=m?a.position[0]:j[0];q=s();a.modal&&b('<div class="bModal '+d+'"></div>').css({"background-color":a.modalColor,height:"100%",left:0,opacity:0,position:"fixed",top:0,width:"100%","z-index":a.zIndex+k}).each(function(){a.appending&&b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo)}).animate({opacity:a.opacity},a.fadeSpeed);c.data("bPopup",a).data("id",d).css({left:!a.follow[0]&&m||i?g:h.scrollLeft()+g,position:a.positionStyle||"absolute",top:!a.follow[1]&&l||i?f:h.scrollTop()+f,"z-index":a.zIndex+k+1}).each(function(){a.appending&&b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo);if(null!=a.loadUrl)switch(a.contentContainer=b(a.contentContainer||c),a.content){case "iframe":b('<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>').attr("src",a.loadUrl).appendTo(a.contentContainer);break;default:a.contentContainer.load(a.loadUrl)}}).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed,function(){b.isFunction(p)&&p.call(c);u()})}function o(){a.modal&&b(".bModal."+c.data("id")).fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed,function(){b(this).remove()});c.stop().fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed,function(){null!=a.loadUrl&&a.contentContainer.empty()});e.data("bPopup",0<e.data("bPopup")-1?e.data("bPopup")-1:null);a.scrollBar||b("html").css("overflow","auto");b("."+a.closeClass).die("click."+d);b(".bModal."+d).die("click");h.unbind("keydown."+d);e.unbind("."+d);c.data("bPopup",null);b.isFunction(a.onClose)&&setTimeout(function(){a.onClose.call(c)},a.fadeSpeed);return!1}function u(){e.data("bPopup",k);b("."+a.closeClass).live("click."+d,o);a.modalClose&&b(".bModal."+d).live("click",o).css("cursor","pointer");(a.follow[0]||a.follow[1])&&e.bind("scroll."+d,function(){q&&c.stop().animate({left:a.follow[0]&&!i?h.scrollLeft()+g:g,top:a.follow[1]&&!i?h.scrollTop()+f:f},a.followSpeed)}).bind("resize."+d,function(){if(q=s())j=r(c,a.amsl),a.follow[0]&&(g=m?g:j[0]),a.follow[1]&&(f=l?f:j[1]),c.stop().each(function(){i?b(this).css({left:g,top:f},a.followSpeed):b(this).animate({left:m?g:g+h.scrollLeft(),top:l?f:f+h.scrollTop()},a.followSpeed)})});a.escClose&&h.bind("keydown."+d,function(a){27==a.which&&o()})}function r(a,b){var c=(e.width()-a.outerWidth(!0))/2,d=(e.height()-a.outerHeight(!0))/2-b;return[c,20>d?20:d]}function s(){return e.height()>c.outerHeight(!0)+20&&e.width()>c.outerWidth(!0)+20}b.isFunction(n)&&(p=n,n=null);var a=b.extend({},b.fn.bPopup.defaults,n);a.scrollBar||b("html").css("overflow","hidden");var c=this,h=b(document),e=b(window),k,d,q,l,m,i,j,f,g;this.close=function(){a=c.data("bPopup");o()};return this.each(function(){c.data("bPopup")||t()})};b.fn.bPopup.defaults={amsl:50,appending:!0,appendTo:"body",closeClass:"bClose",content:"ajax",contentContainer:null,escClose:!0,fadeSpeed:250,follow:[!0,!0],followSpeed:500,loadUrl:null,modal:!0,modalClose:!0,modalColor:"#000",onClose:null,onOpen:null,opacity:0.7,position:["auto","auto"],positionStyle:"absolute",scrollBar:!0,zIndex:9997}})(jQuery);
```

```css
#element_to_pop_up {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<a data-toggle="tooltip" id="my-button" href='#' title="Edit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-pencil">pencil</i> </a>

</form>
<div id="element_to_pop_up">Popping it up</div>
```

Comment: Sir, after studying ur example , i implemented accordingly but now it gives error as " $(...).bPopup is not a function" , feeling very helpless now .

Comment: So that means you probably don't have the bPopup library being included. It's trying to reference the `bPopup()`, but it can't find that it exists.

Comment: Have you downloaded the library, and are including it on that page?

Comment: Yes , sir . Of course i have included that bpopup library.

Comment: Sir , one more thing is that , you have surrounded the anchor tag with form . but my code isn't dat way .Also putting a form tag disturbs my deisgn , so may that be a problem ?

Comment: And is your selector working? If your `$('#element_to_pop_up')` does not match the ID, or if there is no ID, then you'll get a similar error.

Comment: Also, it depends on what order things are happening. 
When are you loading the bpopup library? In the head/footer? (it shouldn't matter if you're using `$(document).ready()`. And are you loading jquery before the library?

Comment: I added the `form` element, because of the code you are trying to use: `appendTo: 'form',`. So I assumed you had some form that you were trying to attach to.

Comment: If you don't have `form`, then in the JavaScript, you should change `appendTo: 'form',` to `appendTo: 'body'`. Or some other element on the page.

Comment: Sir, it would be very kind of you if u can see my code live on skype or something , because your suggestions are very close to what my problem is . So plz if u can....

Comment: Give me a link to the code please. And then I can review it.

Comment: If we move the conversation to Skype, then others won't be able to see the solution.

Comment: Sir , i have uploaded my code on Dropbox and it's link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/2e2m8d5qka5l1an/stk.zip?dl=0